# Capistrano 3 does not restart after deploy

Tags: ruby, capistrano3

I've recently updated my [capistrano](/questions/tagged/capistrano) gem to version 3.1.0, and since then `cap production deploy` passes fine, but the target `deploy:restart` is not called.

My server is deployed on Ubuntu 12.10 on Amazon EC2.

Why could that be?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Capistrano 3 no longer runs that task by default as many app servers don't require it.  Add this to your config/deploy.rb:

```
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

From the [release notes](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/releases/tag/v3.1.0):

> Breaking changes:
>
> - `deploy:restart` task **is no longer run by default**.
>     From this version, developers who restart the app on each deploy need to declare it in their deploy flow (eg `after
>     'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'`).
>
>   Please, check [4e6523e](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/4e6523e1f50707499cf75eb53dce37a89528a9b0) for more information. (@kirs)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using namespaces, you can also do the following:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "My description"
  task :my_task do
    #do something
  end
  after :publishing, :my_task
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in file 'production.rb' I had this `roles: %w{web, app, db}` which prevent block `on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do` in file "deploy.rb" from correct execution.You see, it needs to be `roles: %w{web app db}`